# Create separate pipelines in Jenkins from same jobs with different parameters

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm currently setting up a couple of Continuous Integration pipelines in Jenkins. I've installed all the plugins for building and visualizing pipelines, and have them working, but there's a lot of redundancy in the job configuration.

I have 2 Git branches, master and develop, and a pipeline for each. They're triggered when a commit is made to the respective branch. Each pipeline has to perform the same tasks:

- Build code
- Provision a system
- Deploy artifacts
- Run integration tests
- Publish artifacts

At the moment I have 2 copies of each of these jobs, one for master, one for develop.

I know I can parameterize the jobs, but if I do that, as far as I can tell, they will show up as one pipeline in the Build Pipeline and Delivery Pipeline plugin views, and it then becomes difficult to see the separate status of each pipeline.

Does anyone know how I can create separate pipelines using the same jobs but with different parameters? Also welcome any suggestions of alternate approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Job DSL Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) to maintain your job configuration in a script and generate multiple pipelines from that configuration.

A Job DSL script to generate two pipelines would look like this:

```
['master', 'develop'].each { branch ->
  job("${branch}-compile") {
    scm {
      git("https://repo.example.org/foo.git", branch)
    }
    steps {
      maven('verify')
    }
    publishers {
      downstream("${branch}-provision")
    }
  }

  job("${branch}-provision") {
    // ...
  }

  buildPipelineView("${branch}-pipeline") {
    selectedJob("${branch}-compile")
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh - great! Thanks @daspilker!